# Keep a drive mounted on OS X

Tags: macos, unix, finder, launchd, webdav

I have a WebDav drive that I'd like to keep permanently mounted in the Finder (it's used by a script).  What's the best way of ensuring that it gets immediately remounted if it ever gets disconnected?

I've been looking at launchd (via Lingon) but not sure exactly how this could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two articles that should help you:

First, how to mount web_dav from the command line (needed for the second bit)

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020207214002198&query=mount_webdav

Then, you need to spend some time with automount, described here:

[How to automount SMB shared network drives in Mac OS X Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/336665/how-to-automount-smb-shared-network-drives-in-mac-os-x-lion)
And yes, I know that's SMB not webdav, which is why I posted the link about mounting webdav from the command line.  You just need to combine the two articles.

Another option is to put the commands you learned from the first link in a shell script.  You can then call that shell script automatically with something like [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/)