# How can I disable AFP to use SMB in the Finder by default in Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)?

Tags: macos, network-shares, smb, afp

When I connect to network volumes through the Finder in Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) it uses AFP instead SMB. As result I can't clean `.AppleDouble` files using `BlueHarvest`. I want the Finder to use SMB by default to make `BlueHarvest` works correctly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've used automount for SMB shares. So now SMB is used in the Finder. More information can be found here: [How to automount SMB shared network drives in Mac OS X Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/336665/how-to-automount-smb-shared-network-drives-in-mac-os-x-lion/409051#409051) (answer with using AppleScript)