# How can I disable AFP on Debian?

Tags: debian, smb, bonjour, afp, netatalk

I need to disable AFP protocol on Debian server to force the Finder (Mac OS X) to use SMB. If I stop `netatalk` service the Finder still shows the device with AFP shares but raises error. So we should stop delegating AFP in `Bonjour` service, I think. How can I do this?

P.S. Debian server is NAS `WD MacBook Live Duo`.

Comment: Related but another question: http://superuser.com/questions/986104/how-can-i-disable-afp-to-use-smb-in-the-finder-by-default-in-mac-os-x-10-11-el

Comment: The Zeroconf/Bonjour suite these days is typically implemented on GNU/Linux platforms using the Avahi software package. So I'd check if you have [`avahi-daemon`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/avahi-daemon) installed and running and would consequently try disabling/uninstalling it.

Comment: But can I leave `Avahi` for SMB shares? It `Avahi` doesn't support SMB?

Comment: But what for? SMB/CIFS is served using [`samba`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/samba) on GNU/Linux systems.

Comment: Please post an answer if you know how to disable `Avahi`.

Comment: Does [this](http://ccm.net/faq/739-disabling-the-avahi-daemon) help? [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5430/how-to-stop-avahi-daemon)?